# Confusion regarding special parahoric subgroups of the unitary group

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups, buildings

This question is to clarify some confusion about special parahoric subgroups of a unitary group $G = \mathrm U_n(F)$ in an odd number of variables, with respect to an unramified quadratic extension $E/F$ of $p$-adic fields where $p\geq 3$.

If I write $n=2m+1$, then the group $G$ has $m+1$ conjugacy classes of maximal open compact subgroups and they are all parahorics, equal to the stabilizer of some vertex of a certain type in the Bruhat-Tits building of the derived group $\mathrm{SU}_n(F)$. Only one conjugacy class consists of hyperspecial subgroups.

From Vollaard and Wedhorn's paper where the geometry of the supersingular locus of some unitary PEL Shimura variety is described, it sounds like all these maximal parahoric subgroups are special. Here is a quotation following Proposition 6.4

> The groupe $C_p^{(t)}$ [...] are special parahoric subgroups of $J$ corresponding to vertices in the Bruhat-Tits building.

There, $C_p^{(t)}$ denotes the stabilizer in $J = \mathrm{GU}_n(F)$ of a vertex corresponding to the type $t$ - there are $m+1$ such types, one for each conjugacy class.

However, in other sources I read that only *two* conjugacy classes of parahoric subgroups are special. For instance in Minguez' chapter on unramified representations of unitary groups, one may read the following in paragraph 3.2.2

> the number of conjugacy classes of maximal compact subgroups of a unitary group $\mathrm U(V)$ is equal to $w(V)+1$ [here, $= m+1$]. [...] two of them consist of special compact subgroups

Arzdorf's paper on local models with special parahoric level structure seems to agree with this. At the beginning of section 2, one may read the following.

> we consider the cases $I=\{0\}$ and $I=\{m\}$ [...] these are exactly the index sets for which the parahoric subgroups $P_I$ that preserve the lattice sets $\Lambda_i$ with $i\in I$ are *special* in the sense of Bruhat-Tits theory.

I may be misunderstanding something here, but it looks like the statements contradict each other. Or, could it be that non special parahoric subgroups in $\mathrm U_n$ become special once we consider them in $\mathrm{GU}_n$ ?

Comment: 1) I could not figure out the reference to Vollard--Wedhorn, Prop 6.4. In their [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.1522) there is no prop.6.4.  Or do you mean some other article?

Comment: 2) The group $U_n$ with $n$ odd is of type ${}^2A_{n-1}$. Moreover, as far as I understand, when the splitting field is unramified, the "local Dynkin diagram" is of type ${}^2A_{n-1}'$, see p.63 (and p.67) of Tits article "Reductive groups over local fields". As one sees from Tits classification, in this case there is precisely one hyperspecial vertex, and precisely one special, which is not hyperspecial.

Comment: @alexivanov I see, thanks a lot for the precise reference. This clears one thing ; the other would be to understand what is meant in Vollaard-Wedhorn's paper. It looks like the arxiv version of the article has a different numbering than the published version. In your URL, the paragraph I quoted is just after proposition 5.4. Also, the parameter t is replaced with the letter d there

Comment: I would guess that they meant "maximal parahoric", as Alex Ivanov explained above only two of them are special.

Comment: By the way it might be nice to point out that Proposition 6.4 can be restated as saying that the supersingular locus $\mathcal{M}^{\text{ss}}_{C^p}$ has the same number of connected components as the Shimura variety $\mathcal{M}_{C^p}$.

Comment: @PolvanHoften This sounds reasonable ; thanks for the clarification. Indeed, the formula given in Proposition 6.4 agrees with that giving the number of c.c. of the special fiber of the Shimura variety